# Passar valor para outra pagina

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida meio básica, quero passar um valor de uma página para outra e são várias `divs` com planos e teria que receber um desses planos: "básico" , "médio", "avançado". Está assim a `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <input type="submit" name="basic" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="submit" name="medio" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="submit" name="avancado" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     </div>
```

Como posso passar o valor de uma página para outra?

Comment: Tens alguma tentativa?, você inseriu a tag `PHP`, mas não estou vendo código `PHP` nenhum.

Answer (score 2):

Para enviar os valores para uma página php pode incluir um formulário e especificar a página no atributo `action` do formulário.

A escolha do plano pode ficar assim numa caixa de seleção, construída através da etiqueta `select`.

```html
<form action="pagina.php" method="POST">

  <div class="col-md-3">
    Plano 
    <select name="plano">
      <option value="basic">Basico</option>
      <option value="medio">Médio</option>
      <option value="avancado">Avançado</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo seguindo o que você postou, você tem duas formas, uma seria passar por um form, outra usando jQuery (mas acho que não é essa opção que você quer). 
Segue o exemplo

```
    <form action="outraPage.php" method="POST">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="submit" name="basic" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
         <input type="submit" name="medio" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> 
         </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
         <input type="submit" name="avancado" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> 
         </div>
    </form>

    // Outra Page
<?php
  echo $_POST['avancado'];
  echo $_POST['medio'];
  echo $_POST['basic'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar na página PHP você pode usar assim (já que o `name=` muda):

```
<?php
//Verifica os valores que foram enviados
if (!empty($_POST['basic']) {
    $plano = 'basico';
} else if (!empty($_POST['medio'])) {
    $plano = 'medio';
} else if (!empty($_POST['avancado'])) {
    $plano = 'avancado';
} else {
    die('Escolha um plano'); //Finaliza o PHP e emite erro
}

echo 'Você escolheu o plano: ', $plano;
```

> Se estiver usando GET ao invés de POST, troque todos `$_POST` por `$_GET`

Sobre o HTML, **não tem problema algum** em usar mais de um `<input type=submit>`, o navegador irá reconhecer qual o botão `submit` que você usou e, ao clicar, ele muda o valor e a "chave" da requisição, por exemplo isto:

```
<form id="meuform" method="POST" action="pagina">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" name="basic" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" name="medio" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" name="avancado" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Ao clicar em "basic" veja como o navegador enviou:

[image: basic]

Ao clicar em "avancado":

[image: avancado]

### Extra: Atributo `form=` no HTML5

Uma sugestão é, se você estiver com o formulário em outro "local" da página, usar o atributo `form=` (que é somente disponível com navegadores com suporte para HTML 5, ainda sim para navegadores mais antigos pode usar um *polyfill*).

O que você deve fazer primeiro é colocar os inputs do tipo `submit` **"fora"** do `<form>` e setar um id neste formulário, um exemplo `id="meuform"`, deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<form id="meuform">
...
</form>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <input form="meuform" type="submit" name="basic" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
     <input form="meuform" type="submit" name="medio" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary"> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
     <input form="meuform" type="submit" name="avancado" value="Choose this Plan" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução ainda é utilizar o elemento `button`:

```
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="">Label</button>
```

Quando definido o tipo como sendo `submit` e possuir o atributo `value` definido, gera-se um par chave/valor nas informações enviadas pelo formulário ao submetê-lo, assim como ocorre com o elemento `input`. Desta forma, seria possível ter os elementos:

```
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="basico">Escolha o plano básico</button>
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="medio">Escolha o plano médio</button>
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="avancado">Escolha o plano avançado</button>
```

No PHP, para recuperar este valor, bastaria utilizar `$_POST` ou `$_GET`, dependendo no método utilizado pelo formulário:

```
<?php

switch ($_POST["plano"]) {
    case "basico":
        echo "Você escolhe o plano básico", PHP_EOL;
        break;
    case "medio":
        echo "Você escolhe o plano médio", PHP_EOL;
        break;
    case "avancado":
        echo "Você escolhe o plano avançado", PHP_EOL;
        break;
}
```

> Veja a [especificação W3C do elemento](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.submit.html#button.submit) para mais detalhes.

A principal vantagem deste método em relação a resposta do [Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218789/5878) é que utilizando `button` é possível definir o mesmo valor do atributo `name` para todos os botões, variando o valor em `value`. Desta forma, no PHP, basta fazer a validação em um valor e não em três, como é utilizando o `input`.

Inclusive fazer o apresentado acima nem é tão indicado. O ideal seria, caso os planos existentes estivessem armazenados no banco de dados, associar o valor do botão com o valor do `id` do plano e não com o valor do nome. Algo como:

```
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="1">Escolha o plano básico</button>
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="2">Escolha o plano médio</button>
<button type="submit" name="plano" value="3">Escolha o plano avançado</button>
```

E no PHP bastaria fazer:

```
$plano = $_POST["plano"];
```

Podendo salvar o valor no banco de dados diretamente.